# How I can determine $\dim(U)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
U = \bigl\{ p(x) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid 3p(1) = 2p'(1) \bigr\}
$$

How I can determine the $\dim(U)$?

What I tried was an arbitrary $p$ like, $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and then doing an equation with both conditions. I got to the value of constants must be: $3a+b-c-3d = 0$

Do that means that I can reduce the condition to
$U = \bigl\{ (a,b,c,d) \mid 3a+b-c-3d = 0 \bigr\}$?

If so, what is the dimension of that?

Comment: What does $p(x) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ mean? Do you mean that $p$ is a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$? So the equation that defines the elements of the set $U$ involves vectors? If so, what is the cubic polynomial? One of its coordinates?

Comment: Hint: Think about a certain null space.

Comment: Or do you mean that $p$ belongs to the vector space of polynomials of degree at most $3$, and you're considering a subspace of this finite dimensional space? That's a pretty standard example of a vector space, sometimes denoted $P_3$ or something. Please clarify where $U$ lives!

Comment: Oh I forgot that! with p(x)∈R3 I mean it is a polynomial which maximum grade is 3

Answer (score 1):

Just isolate one variable from your equations, e.g. $c$:
\begin{align*}
U &= \{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d : a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R,\, 3a+b-c-3d = 0\} \\
&= \{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d : a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R,\, c=3a+b-3d\} \\
&= \{ax^3+bx^2+(3a+b-3d)x+d : a,b,d \in \Bbb R\} \\
&= \{a(x^3+3)+b(x^2+x)+d(-3x) : a,b,d \in \Bbb R\}.
\end{align*}
This means that $x^3+3$, $x^2+x$ and $-3x$ spans $U$. If you prove that these three polynomials are linearly independent, then they form a basis for $U$. Hence, $\dim U = 3$.

Comment: Thanks man! I got it very clear

Answer (score 0):

Let $U=\{p\in P_3(\mathbb{R}):3p(1)=2p'(1)\}$.
As you noted, we have $U=\{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d:3a+b-c-3d=0\}$.
We know that $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$ via the map $\phi:ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\mapsto (a,b,c,d)$.
Then $\phi(U)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ isomorphic to $U$.
Explicitly, we have $\phi(U)=\{(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^4:3a+b-c-3d=0\}$,
so that
$$
\phi(U)=\ker
\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 & -1 & -3\end{bmatrix}.
$$
We easily see that the rank of this matrix is $1$, so its kernel has dimension $3$
and hence $U$ has dimension $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $U = \ker A$, where $A : \mathbb{P}_3 \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $Ap = 2p(1)-3p'(1)$. Then rank nullity gives $\dim{\cal R} A + \dim \ker A = \dim \mathbb{P}_3 = 4$, and since $A \ne 0$ we see that $\dim{\cal R} A = 1$ hence $\dim U = 3$.